# PostGIS for PHP-Mysql (cakephp)

Tags: php, mysql, postgis

Is there any library similar to PostGIS for PHP-Mysql? I'm dealing with hundreds of GeoLocations in a project than involves geo-boundary + statistics + cakephp-mysql, I want to improve the performance on the server-side not only on PHP-side as well as in MySql. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [Spatial Extensions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html).

Comment: Also, there are plans in MariaDB for adding functionality - improving performanace of GIS: https://beta.montyprogram.com/en/plans-for-56

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no such a library.

In our project we had to migrate to Postgresql to use PostGIS.